# How do I get access to the vertex color to modify the DFS search?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to find all the paths between a start and end point in a BGL diagram. For this, I use the DFS algorithm. Unfortunately, the DFS marks already visited Vetrex and I don't get any paths which contain a Vetrex several times. The graph looks like this:

[image]

My approach is to record the visited node in a stack until the destination node is found. Then I save this path and deselect all nodes in this path up to the start node. From there the search starts again. If no destination is found and the current node has no outgoing edges, I discard this path and the search starts again until all paths are searched by the start node. I implemented this modified search in a simple C++ program and it works. Now I want to use the BGL, but I'm stuck with the problem of being able to deselect the nodes I've already used.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

namespace graphProps {
    struct VertexProps {
        unsigned int vertexID;
        std::string vertexName;
    };

    struct EdgeProps {
        unsigned int edgeID;
        std::string edgeName;
    };
}

typedef boost::adjacency_list <
    boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    //vertex properties
    boost::property <
    boost::vertex_name_t, std::string,
    boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int, graphProps::VertexProps> >,
    //edge properties
    boost::property<
    boost::edge_weight_t, int,
    boost::property<boost::edge_index_t, int, graphProps::EdgeProps > >,
    boost::property<vertex_color_t, default_color_type>
> mygraph;

typedef boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> _map;
typedef std::pair<mygraph::vertex_descriptor, mygraph::vertex_descriptor> edgePair;
using colormap = std::map<mygraph::vertex_descriptor, default_color_type>;

class PathDFSVisitor :public boost::default_dfs_visitor {

        public:
            colormap vertex_coloring;
            mygraph *m_path;
            std::vector<edgePair> *m_edgePair;
            boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> *m_pathNumMap;
            std::vector<mygraph::vertex_descriptor> m_spath;
            int m_source;
            int m_destination;
            bool m_foundDest = false;
            bool m_pathFinished = false;
            bool *m_result;
            int path_index = 0;


        PathDFSVisitor(boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> *inMap, std::vector<edgePair> *edgePair)
        {
            m_edgePair = edgePair;
            m_pathNumMap = inMap;
        }

        PathDFSVisitor(std::vector<edgePair> *edgePair, int source, int destination, bool *result)
        {
            m_edgePair = edgePair;
            m_source = source;
            m_destination = destination;
            m_result = result;
        }

        template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
        void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g)
        {
            mygraph::vertex_descriptor vertex;
            vertex = boost::vertex(u, g);

            default_color_type color = vertex_coloring[u];
            std::cout << "Discover at: " << u << " with color " << color << std::endl;
            m_spath.push_back(vertex);
            path_index++;
        }

        template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
        void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g)
        {
            mygraph::vertex_descriptor vertex;
            default_color_type color = vertex_coloring[u];
            std::cout << "Finish vertex at: " << u << " with color " << color << std::endl;
            for (int i = path_index; i > 1; i--)
            {
                vertex = boost::vertex(m_spath[i-1], g);
                vertex_coloring[vertex] = white_color;
                std::cout << "Unmarking vertex: " << vertex << std::endl;
                m_spath.pop_back();
                path_index--;
            }
        }


    };

void addVertex(unsigned int vertexID, std::string vertexName, mygraph &graph)
{
    mygraph::vertex_descriptor vert;
    //add vertex and intialize 
    vert = boost::add_vertex(graph);
    graph[vert].vertexID = vertexID;
    graph[vert].vertexName = vertexName;
}

void addEdge(unsigned int edgeID, unsigned int srcVertexID, unsigned int dstVertexID, std::string edgeName, mygraph &graph)
{
    //(1) get vertex descriptor for source and destination vertex
    mygraph::vertex_descriptor src, dst;
    //add vertex and intialize 

    src = boost::vertex(srcVertexID, graph);
    dst = boost::vertex(dstVertexID, graph);
    //set edge properties between source and destination vertex
    boost::add_edge(src, dst, graph);
    //(2)get edge descriptor
    auto e = boost::edge(boost::vertex(srcVertexID, graph), boost::vertex(dstVertexID, graph), graph).first;
    //initialize edge properties
    graph[e].edgeID = edgeID;
    graph[e].edgeName = edgeName;
}

int main()
{
    mygraph g,l; 
    std::vector<edgePair> path;

    addVertex(0, "A", g);
    addVertex(1, "B", g);
    addVertex(2, "C", g);
    addVertex(3, "D", g);
    addVertex(4, "E", g);
    addVertex(5, "F", g);

    addEdge(0, 1, 0, "BA", g);
    addEdge(1, 1, 4, "BD", g);
    addEdge(2, 1, 2, "BC", g);
    addEdge(2, 0, 3, "AD", g);
    addEdge(3, 4, 3, "ED", g);
    addEdge(4, 4, 2, "EC", g);
    addEdge(5, 3, 5, "DF", g);
    addEdge(6, 3, 1, "DB", g);
    addEdge(6, 4, 1, "EB", g);

    bool searchState = false;
    std::size_t start = 1;
    std::size_t stop = 5;
    PathDFSVisitor vis(&path,start,stop,&searchState);
    depth_first_search(g, visitor(vis).root_vertex(start));

    //build graph which contains (only) all paths between start and stop vertex 
    std::vector<edgePair>::iterator it;
    for (it = path.begin(); it != path.end(); ++it)
    {
        boost::add_edge(it->first, it->second, l);
    }

    std::ofstream f("Graph.dot");
    write_graphviz(f, g);
    f.close();
    system("renderGraph.bat");

    std::cin.get();
}
```

**The output is:**

```
Discover at: 1 with color 0
Discover at: 0 with color 0
Discover at: 3 with color 0
Discover at: 5 with color 0
Finish vertex at: 5 with color 0
Unmarking vertex: 5
Unmarking vertex: 3
Unmarking vertex: 0
Finish vertex at: 3 with color 0
Finish vertex at: 0 with color 0
Discover at: 4 with color 0
Discover at: 2 with color 0
Finish vertex at: 2 with color 0
Unmarking vertex: 2
Unmarking vertex: 4
Finish vertex at: 4 with color 0
Finish vertex at: 1 with color 0
```

And my simple working algorithm produces this:
Following are all different paths from 1 to 5

```
Add vertex: 1 to path.
Add vertex: 0 to path.
Add vertex: 3 to path.
Add vertex: 5 to path.
1 0 3 5
Unmark vertex: 5
Unmark vertex: 3
Unmark vertex: 0
Add vertex: 4 to path.
Add vertex: 3 to path.
Add vertex: 5 to path.
1 4 3 5
Unmark vertex: 5
Unmark vertex: 3
Add vertex: 2 to path.
Unmark vertex: 2
Unmark vertex: 4
Add vertex: 2 to path.
Unmark vertex: 2
Unmark vertex: 1
```

{1,0,3,5} and {1,4,3,5} are the two paths I want to get..